# Как сделать что б переменная брала своё значение из последующего кода, а не из предыдущего?

Tags: python-3.x

например, переменная

```
x = 5 
f = x + 4
print(f) # 9 
x = 6 + 4 + 3 # x принимает значение 13
```

как сделать что б это значение 13 передавалось в X заменяя значение 5, и что б потом со значением 13 высчитывалась f?

Comment: А какие проблемы? Берите и делайте то, что написали. Дословно. Это предельно просто.,

Comment: `x = 6 + 4 + 3` `f = x + 4` Не так?

Comment: Нужно именно задать переменную, а присвоить ей значение после задания

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "задать"? В питоне переменные не инициализируются. Им сразу задается значение. Если вы хотите задать какое-то значение переменной — берите и задавайте.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так x у вас уже приняло значение 13 и заменило 5. Просто высчитайте значение f снова наверное?

```py
x = 5 
f = x + 4
print(f) # 9 
x = 6 + 4 + 3 # x принимает значение 13
f = x + 4
print(f) # 17
```

**EDIT:** Вообще не понимаю что вам нужно, но вот:

```py
x = 5 
x = 6 + 4 + 3 # x принимает значение 13
f = x + 4
print(f) # 9
```

Comment: В том то и дело что нельзя снова высчитать f нужно именно присвоить новое значение x в начале кода. Может использовать глобальные параметры как нибудь?

Comment: Ну так просто перенесите вычисление нового значения x в начало...

Comment: @Pawel3893 обновил ответ

Comment: Вопрос такой, сначала объявляется переменная, с помощью неё происходят вычисления, потом значение этой переменной уточняется и это уточнение должно передаться в изначальное объявление переменной, изначально уточнить переменную а потом её задать нельзя

Comment: @Pawel3893 Ну есть конечно вариант с сигналами...

Comment: @Pawel3893 Но по сути это то же перевычесление переменной

Comment: С какими сигналами? Первый раз слышу.

Comment: @Глеб Сигналы в движках и других сложных проектах это концепция значения, которые зависят от других значений. Короче это уже черезчур лишнее и бесполезное переусложнение

Comment: Хз, обычно их назвают сигналами, вот я так же называю

Comment: А в питоне такое разве есть? Или оно в каких-то библиотеках?

Comment: @Глеб Не, это чисто концепция. Не знаю почему, сразу в голову прилетели они. Может потому что много с ними работал в последнее время)

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать в конечном итоге.

Но вообще, если есть потребность разделить задание некоторого значения и его использование, чтобы чередовать их в произвольном порядке, то мне сразу приходит в голову использовать класс. Это будет выглядеть немного сложнее, чем вы хотите, но будет работать так же.

```
# Определяем класс
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self.x + 4

# Используем класс
a = A()
print(a.f)  # Выведет 9
a.x = 6 + 4 + 3  # a.x принимает значение 13
print(a.f)  # Выведет 17, т.к. 13+4=17
```

Answer (score 1):

Звучит так, как будто это нужно делать в цикле. Но больше двух итераций делать бессмысленно, т.к. после первой итерации `x` уже не меняется. (Возможно, это попытка посчитать рекуррентную формулу?)

```
x = 5
for _ in range(2):
    f = x + 4
    print(f)  # 9
    x = 6 + 4 + 3  # x принимает значение 13
```

```
9
17
```